# generating a text field dynamically on clicking previous text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

i am trying to generate a textfield by clicking a previous textfield

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="text1" class="XYZ"/><input type="button" value="button"/>
```

javascript

```
$(function () {
    count=2;
    var createNewField = function () {
        var $node = $('<input type="radio" name="choices" name="o" id="o" /><div class="ABC"><input class="XYZ" type="text" name="op" id="op"/></div>');

        $node.one('click', createNewField);
        $(this).after($node);
    };

    $('input.XYZ').one('click', createNewField);
});
```

This script is working fine. The problem is

i want to generate a textfield on clicking on the previous textfield, but in this new text field is generated even on clicking the radio button.

Secondly how can i adjust the position of the generated textfield. For eg. i want the new textfield to be after a button. But this script generate the textfield before the button.

Hope you understood the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I indented your code, but you were missing a closing `'`.  I added it where it seemed appropriate assuming this was not missing from the real code.

Comment: Your $node assignment lacks a closing quote. Please create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you only want the handler on `input.XYZ` but you are adding it to everything in `$node`.

Instead of

```
$node.one( ...
```

Do this

```
$node.find("input.XYZ").one( ...
```

Comment: what about the positioning problem??

Comment: The 2nd bit is pretty vague.  You might want to make that a separate question and include more detail of the actual case.